# What's the preferred way to get a specific tag from an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm tagging EBS snapshots based on the `Name` of the `instance-id` from which the `vol-id` is attached.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_volume = event["detail"]["source"]
    source_volume_id = 'vol-' + source_volume.split('vol-', 1)[1]
    volume_detail = client.describe_volumes(
        VolumeIds=[
            source_volume_id,
        ]
    )

    instance = client.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[
            volume_detail['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId']
        ]
    )
    for pair in instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']:
        if pair['Key'] == 'Name' and pair['Value'] == 'my-tag':
            return pair
```

I'd like to eliminate the looping if possible - is there a way to query just the specific tag, `Name`, from my instance?

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/Answers4AWS/graffiti-monkey.

Comment: Have you looked at `jmespath` (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html#filtering-results-with-jmespath)?